# Mounting from persistent storage into azure multi container app

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm trying to build a multiconatiner app with azure. I'm struggling with accessing persistent storage. In my docker-compose file I want to add the config file for my rabbitmq container. I've mounted a fileshare to the directory "/home/fileshare" which contains the def.json. On the cloud it doesn't seem to create the volume, as on startup rabbitmq can't find the file. If i do this locally and just save the file somewhere it works.

Docker Compose File:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

   rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
      volumes:
       - /home/fileshare/def.json:/opt/rabbitmq-conf/def.json
      expose:
        - 5672
        - 15672
      environment:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
        RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS: -rabbitmq_management load_definitions "/opt/rabbitmq-conf/def.json"
      networks:
        - cloudnet 
        
networks:
   cloudnet:
      driver: bridge
```

Comment: I have now also tried to use `${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/home/fileshare/def.json:/opt/rabbitmq-conf/def.json`. I added the /home to the path, since i figured that ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} might not point to the home directory

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem? What is the reason you do not give any response?! It's simple to accept it if it works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem seems to be to use ftp to access the webapp and save the definitions file. Docker-Compose is in preview mode (since 2018), and a lot of the options are actually not supported. I tried mounting the storage to a single container app and used ssh to connect to it, and the file is exactly where one would expect it to be. With a multi-container app this doesn't work.
I feel like the docker-compose feature is not yet fully supported

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME** env variable that is mapped to persistent storage at /home.

```
${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/fileshare/def.json:/opt/rabbitmq-conf/def.json
```

Comment: This only results in the following error from the rabbitmq container `2020-09-24T13:46:23.875893469Z {"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{error,{could_not_read_defs,{"/opt/rabbitmq-conf/def.json",enoent}}}}}`.

I also can't ssh to the host machine via the "azure portal" to check if the mount worked, only getting the following error: `SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Couldnt connect to main site containerError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Couldnt connect to main site container
CREDENTIALS`

Comment: Try testing using a test container like busybox to see if the mapping to persistent storage works.

Comment: I used busybox and added the volume in a similar way,but changed the target to `/home/rabbitmq-conf/def.json` as the rabbitmq image. I passed `ls /home` as command and it's empty...
So to me it seems like the ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} does not point to /home, as @CSharpRocks suggests

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in this tutorial they actually do something different. They create a docker volume in the webapp... what i'm trying to do is to get a file into a container and not map container storage into webapp so that i can persist the data of the container.

Answer (score 0):

On my understanding, you want to mount the Azure File Share to the container rabbitmq and upload the def.json file to the file share so that you can access the def.json file inside the container.

Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux) to mount the file share to the container. And it just supports to mount the file share, not the file directly.

Comment: Yes, you get what I'm trying to do. As explained in the answer above I've already tried those steps you are suggesting, but with a multi-container app i'm not able to access the mounted directory.

Comment: @Alex Why not access the mounted directory? If you enable the SSH, you can also access it. And mount the Azure storage, you just need to upload the files to the storage. I don't understand why you think it's not possible.

Comment: When using a single container app i cann just use ssh to connect to the machine it's running on and i can see the mounted files, on the multi-container app I am not able to connect through ssh. So for the single container app the mount works, and the file is where i expect it to be. WIth the multi-container app it doesn't seem to work as I'm not able to get the file into the container.